# Deep Reinforcement Learning model takes different action even a state is the same

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am a beginner in the DRL field and have been working on a DRL model.
These days I have been doing inference that I give states to the model and see which actions the model takes.

I defined a state as 3-dimensional Numpy array and give it to the model, and it returns a different combination of actions every time I run the code even it is definitely the same state.

My question is that is it what the DRL's behavior is? Or does it sound weird?

I trained it just on 5 episodes which could cause it?

If anyone gives me thoughts I'd grateful to you.

Comment: Usually agents include some form of exploration (noise), i.e. a component that will make them select an action at random. This causes different actions to be sampled even for the same state. For evaluation of the model, you can turn off that exploration noise.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I appreciate it.